# Adding mobile web app to home screen using button

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to add app to home screen via button located in "settings" page of my HTML5 mobile web app (Notice: It is working if I'm trying to add it via Chrome menu).

I've set up all of these steps:

- The PWA must not already be installed
- Web app must include a web app manifest.
- Web app must be served over a secure HTTPS connection.
- Web app has registered a service worker with a fetch event handler.

Currently I'm debugging it via Chrome Dev tools and listening to `beforeinstallprompt` with that code from official docs.

```
<script>
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(event) {
  // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
});

// Installation must be done by a user gesture! Here, the button click
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
  btnAdd.style.display = 'none';
  // Show the prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  deferredPrompt.userChoice
    .then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
});

</script>
```

How to catch event on `/home` page, and pass it to `/settings` page so I could fire the event via `(onClick)` event?

Currently I'm using:
   Angular CLI: 6.1.4
   Node: 8.11.4
   OS: win32 x64

Comment: Does your manifest contain the following: short_name, name, start_url, icon of size 192x192? 
You have all the other app requirements but there is another requirement user-wise that is: Receive visits at least twice, with at least five minutes of difference between visits. In order for the option to appear. [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/?hl=en)

Comment: Yes, everything is set up correctly. I tried runing Lighthouse and I've got the result "User can be prompted to install the Web App", So I guess this is alright. My question is how to pass those event between two different pages.

Comment: Isn't it  just a matter of using `deferredPrompt.prompt()` when you are on the `/settings` page?

Answer (score 0):

Save it to global (`window`) object (or somewhere else with global access) and on `/settings` page in event handler call `window.deferredPrompt.prompt()`?